# Send virtual keys with Python (for zoom functioning)

Tags: python, mouseevent, keyboard-shortcuts, zooming, keyboard-events

Is it possible to virtually send the input of `ctrl + mouse scroll`.

Is there any library that can perform this action? Maybe a special implemented command or even by invoking virtual mouse-keyboard events?

Comment: What kind of function? What do you want to zoom in to?

Comment: @marke updated, thanks.

Comment: mouse zoom in webpages would be controlled in javascript/css ...  if you wanted to imlement this  in a gui that is not a webpage that would be a more appropriate place ... however theres no silver bullet out there ... you need to implement the actual zoom ... but theres plenty to bind to mouse scroll events and ctrl clicks

Comment: Yes. Myabe I was unclear, but my aim is not to zoom in a gui or a specific program, but to bind `ctrl + mouse middle button`. Any idea how to implement this? @JoranBeasley

Answer (score 0):

```
import pynput


def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    if pynput.Controller.ctrl_pressed:
        print("You are scrolling with ctrl!!!!")
# Collect events until released
with pynput.Listener(
        on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I guess

Comment: I don't want to detect when ctrl is being used, I want to activate it while activating the scrolling method. Is there any way to call a fake keyboard event?

Comment: `Controller.press(Key.ctrl)` I guess